# wrap_parameters adds parameters in application => {...} hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

When making POST/PATCH requests to my rails webapp, I send the data as json. For example this json data `{"name" => "Hallo", "status" => "admin"}` to an controller named UsersController. The setting for wrap_parameters in the wrap_parameters.rb file are the default values:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  wrap_parameters format: [:json] if respond_to?(:wrap_parameters)
end
```

So every json data gets wrapped like this `"user" => {"name"=> "Hallo", "status" => "admin"}`. This is how it should be. However when I call a custom method called status which is located in ApplicationController to check the server status, all following requests json data won't get wrapped in their controllers/models name hash, but in a hash like this `"application" => {"name"=> "Hallo", "status" => "admin"}`.

This is for all following requests until I restart the server. Moreover if I want to keep the "right" behavior I can't call the status method in ApplicationController again which would lead to the `"application" => {...}`wrapping.

What I found out is when I set Content-Type = text/html (It was Content-Type = application/json before) for my request to the status method the following request are not polluted, meaning I get the right wrapping behavior.

However this is very disturbing, as someone just needs to call the status method, when Content-Type = application/json is set for the request and all the following POST/PATCH requests won't work anylonger.

I don't know if this matters, but I set the following in routes.rb:

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
    namespace :v1 do
       ...
       match "/status", to: "application#status", via: "get"
       ...
    end
end
```

Comment: Try using a dedicated StatusController instead of routing to ApplicationController. ApplicationController is usually only used as superclass and not to be actively called.

Comment: I am pretty sure your troubles come from routing directly to a method on ApplicationController. I would guess this sets the root name to the singular name of the Controller. In subsequent calls the root is already set on the superclass and thus does not get set again in the subclass.

I was - however - not able to reproduce this behavior. Which version of rails are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your help, really appreciate it. You are right it would be better to add the status method in a StatusController, which I will do. I use rails 4.2.5.2.

Comment: I removed all routes directly to ApplicationController. Now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

There's one tricky thing in the `wrap_parameters` method. You can specify the `format` as you did but `ParamsWrapper` is getting the `format` from `request.content_mime_type`instead of `request.format` so if you're trying to do `POST/PUT`request, `ParamsWrapper` format is `multipart_form` and not `json`.

So instead of:

`wrap_parameters format: [:json]`

you have to do:

`wrap_parameters format: [:json, :multipart_form]`

Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/dda31d59a03adb7e5aa372e72bb66a3886632f2f/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb#L281